# WinForms equivalent of Java's JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES

Tags: file, dialog, directory

Java has `JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES` to allow the user to select a file or a folder. .NET WinForms has `OpenFileDialog` for files and `FolderBrowserDialog` for folders. Does .NET have any component that can allow for either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No .NET doesn't have such a component.

However you might try this:

[Select file or folder from the same dialog](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileOrFolderDialog.aspx)